# Accidentally deleted openssl lib packages and can't get yum or wget to work again

Tags: linux, centos, ssl

So I was trying to upgrade openssl and decided to remove the existing openssl packages because it was from a different repository.

Once removed, I can't no longer get either yum or wget to work again because they all seem to rely on ssl

I'm missing the files

```
libssl.so.10
libcrypto.so.10
```

I was able to recover `libssl.so.10` by using `libssl3.so` that existed locally, but not with `libcrypto.so.10` yet (since this file probably need to be downloaded from a remote location).

yum:

```
The error leading to this problem was:
libcrypto.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

wget:

```
wget: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.10:
```

In other words, I'm now in a catch-22; I can't use `yum`, `wget`, `curl`, `rpm (with url)`, or `rsync (by connecting to a backup server instance)` because they all require ssl lib files.

I can't even open a new SSH to the problematic server since SSL lib files is now gone. (can only access with existing Putty prompt).

I try "copy and paste" the file content with VIM editor using another snapshot backup but doesn't seem working.

I'm thinking if there is a way to download a rpm or even a single file over plain http using existing tools not listed above...

Comment: Just nuke it from orbit and restore. Playing with packages is like playing with explosives. You really need to have an idea on what you're doing. Even then it's a terrible idea.

Comment: For a copy-paste solution: you must first uuencode the file ... this is a bad solution anyway.

Comment: What about perl basic LWP::Simple approach (it might not need ssl). Of course, you had to double check the MD5 of any file you get this way. Either `lwp-mirror <url> <file>` or `perl -MLWP::Simple -e 'mirror "<url>", file'` (you need of course Perl and LWP::Simple already installed).

Comment: I wonder whether the actual file contents are still on disk (since the lib is still in use by the existing SSH connection). In superficial tests I found the lib and the inode number in `/proc/<pid>/maps` but couldn't find the file for that inode any more. Anyone has more experience with this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NOT SO GOOD. Try and avoid `--force` in RPM command unless you know what you're doing.

To try and recover to a decent state so you can attempt proper recovery, run from the backup or another identical server:

```
# tar cfz - $(rpm -ql openssl) | base64 > oh_my_god_what_did_I_do
```

Copy the output of that (in the `oh_my_god_what_did_I_do` file) into the clipboard and paste it into the other server:

```
# cat > oh_my_god_what_did_I_do
(paste here)
^D
# cd /; base64 -d < oh_my_god_what_did_I_do | tar xfz -
```

Good luck.

(if you're savvy, you can come up with other ways to move that file. NFS, netcat, it's not hard to find something)

Comment: +1 Thank you MikeyB. Your method worked. The binary data need to be base64 encoded if they are to be transferred by copy & paste.